# Angular $http post not returning Json response

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller

Recipes/CreateRecipe was successful but return Json is not returning anything and goes to the next function which is the alert `Error CreateRecipe null`

**script**

```
$scope.createRecipe = function (recipe) {

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Recipes/CreateRecipe',
    data: JSON.stringify(recipe)
}).then(function (response) {
    if (response!=null) {
        $scope.recipeID = response.data;
        alert($scope.recipeID)
    }
    else {
        alert("get response failed! " + response.data)
    }
}, function (response) { alert('Error CreateRecipe '+response.data); });

};
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateRecipe([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Recipe vm)
    {
            Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
            recipe.Name = vm.Name;
            db.Recipes.Add(recipe);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(recipe.Id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I tried a lot of things like adding `ModelState.IsValid` and checking if `recipe.Id` is null but it wasn't. I also tried changing `JsonResult` to `ActionResult`. Sometimes the alert says `get response failed!` sometimes it's `Error CreateRecipe null`.

Even if I put `recipe.Id` in an int before returning it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you post what you see inside console.log(response.data);

Comment: @Sajeetharan Create Recipe http post doesn't return a response and just goes to the next function which is the error alert and the response there is `null`

Comment: When you return `Json(recipe.Id, ..)`, does recipe.Id have a value?

Comment: @Sajal Yes, it has a value when I check in the controller.

Comment: You should consider making the json result `async` too, when you open the `db` layer, the thread probably doesn't wait for `recipe.Id` and returns a null/undefined value back to angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making the `JsonResult` asynchronous too using the `async` task and save changes to database using `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> CreateRecipe([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Recipe vm)
{
    int recipeId = -1;

    if(vm != null) {
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        recipe.Name = vm.Name;
        db.Recipes.Add(recipe);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        recipeId = recipe.Id;

        if(recipeId > 0) {
            return Json(recipeId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```